# Only execute script if URL parameter exists

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to make this script only execute if a utm_campaign parameter exists in the URL?

```js
function fillFormArea(){
      
  const select = document.getElementById('property.cust_AreaOfInterest.value'); 
  const queryString = window.location.search;
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);  //parse the query string
  const country = urlParams.get('utm_campaign');  // Store the parsed area of interest

   select.value = country;  // fill the form with the area of interest
}

if (document.readyState === 'loading') {  // Loading hasn't finished yet
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fillFormArea)
} 
else {  // `DOMContentLoaded` has already fired
  fillFormArea();
}
```

Comment: `if(country !== null)` to check if the param was passed .. and by the way just check it inside your fillFormArea as the first condition and attach the event listener to the DOMContentLoaded event anyway without doing that convoluted check on document.readystate. The getElementById on that string `property.cust_AreaOfInterest.value` is pretty unclear

Comment: Scripts are executed when they're loaded, you've to check the query parameter on the server side, and not include the script on the page if the parameter is missing. Or check the parameter in the function, and return without doing anything else if the parameter doesn't exist. Why such a complex loading detection? Is the script added dynamically on the page, or is `async` attribute present in the script tag?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const country = urlParams.get('utm_campaign');
if ( country === null) {
//does not exist
}else{
const select = document.getElementById('property.cust_AreaOfInterest.value');
select.value = country
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).